# How to run a basic functional test with selenium webdriver from django

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a python/django project and would like to incorporate some functional tests using selenium webdriver. I've used the selenium IDE firefox plugin to generate a test that looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re    

class Gtest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_g(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "google.com")
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").send_keys("stack")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("b").click()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Following http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/django-1-6-test-driven-development/#.Uucu0sAo6Z4 I put the above script into "gtest.py" which I put into a project root level directory called "ft".

I want to be able to call the this test from a function within my django project and store the result ( pass/fail ) to a db table.  Its not clear to me how best to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I use for running test nosetests sometimes:
https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've gone to the link and looked around but I need more specific info on what to do in my case above. Thanks, -Bill